# QTcpSocket stucks sometimes for dynamic created java script

Tags: qt, proxy, network-programming

I am trying to connect to a website through a proxy. I implemented a QTcpServer and a QTcpSocket.
The server passes the connection to the socket.
It works well, but for some sites, expecially for those which have dynamically created javascript, the socket stucks at some point and nothing is shown in the navigator.
Attach the code, hope clear.

```
            #include "webproxy.h"
            #include <QtNetwork>
            #include <QMessageBox>
            #include <QtGui>
            #include <QHash>


            WebProxy::WebProxy(QObject *parent,int port): QObject(parent)

                {
                    qDebug()<<" Listen...";
                    authMethod = "";
                    QTcpServer *proxyServer = new QTcpServer(this);
                    if (!proxyServer->listen(QHostAddress::Any, port)) {
                       emit error(1);

                        return;
                    }

                    connect(proxyServer, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(manageQuery()));
                    qDebug() << "Proxy server running at port" << proxyServer->serverPort();






            void WebProxy::manageQuery() {
                    QTcpServer *proxyServer = qobject_cast<QTcpServer*>(sender());
                    QTcpSocket *socket = proxyServer->nextPendingConnection();
                    connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(processQuery()));
                    connect(socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), socket, SLOT(deleteLater()));

                    qDebug()<<"New connection started..."<<socket->peerAddress();
                }
            QUrl WebProxy::getUrl(QList<QByteArray > &entries)
               {

                   QByteArray method = entries.value(0);
                   QByteArray address = entries.value(1);
                   QByteArray version = entries.value(2);

                   qDebug()<<method;
                   qDebug()<<address;
                   qDebug()<<version;
                   QUrl url = QUrl::fromEncoded(address);
                   if (!url.isValid()) {

                       qWarning() << "Invalid URL:" << url;

                       return QString();
                   }


                   return url;
               }

              void WebProxy::processQuery() {

                    int wSize = 0;
                    QTcpSocket *socket = qobject_cast<QTcpSocket*>(sender());
                    QByteArray requestData = socket->readAll();


             qDebug()<<"Request "<<requestData;

                    int pos = requestData.indexOf("\r\n");


                    QByteArray requestLine = requestData.left(pos);
                    requestData.remove(0, pos + 2);

                    QList<QByteArray> entries = requestLine.split(' ');
                    QByteArray method         = entries.value(0);
                    QByteArray address        = entries.value(1);
                    QByteArray version        = entries.value(2);

                    QByteArray auth;
                    QByteArray authMethod;

                    QUrl url = QUrl::fromEncoded(address);
                    if (!url.isValid()) {
                        qWarning() << "Invalid URL:" << url;
                        socket->disconnectFromHost();
                        return;
                    }

                    QString host              = url.host();


                    int port = (url.port() <= 0) ? 80 : url.port();
                    QByteArray req = url.encodedPath();
                    if (url.hasQuery())
                        req.append('?').append(url.encodedQuery());


                    requestLine = method + " " + req + " " + version + "\r\n";
                    if (!authMethod.isEmpty())
                    {
                         requestLine.append(requestLine);
                         requestLine.append(authMethod);
                         requestLine.append("\r\n");
                     }

                    QString key = host + ':' + QString::number(port);
                    QTcpSocket *proxySocket = socket->findChild<QTcpSocket*>(key);

                    if (proxySocket) {
                        proxySocket->setObjectName(key);
                        proxySocket->setProperty("url", url);
                        proxySocket->setProperty("requestData", requestData);
                        wSize = proxySocket->write(requestData);


                    } else {
                        proxySocket = new QTcpSocket(socket);
                        proxySocket->setObjectName(key);
                        proxySocket->setProperty("url", url);
                        proxySocket->setProperty("requestData", requestData);
                        connect(proxySocket, SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(sendRequest()));
                        connect(proxySocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(transferData()));
                        connect(proxySocket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(closeConnection()));
                        connect(proxySocket, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)), this, SLOT(closeConnection()));
                        proxySocket->connectToHost(host, port);
                    }
                }

            void WebProxy::sendRequest() {
                    QTcpSocket *proxySocket = qobject_cast<QTcpSocket*>(sender());
                    QByteArray requestData = proxySocket->property("requestData").toByteArray();
                    int wSize = 0;
                    wSize     = proxySocket->write(requestData);

                }

            void WebProxy::transferData() {


                    QTcpSocket *proxySocket = qobject_cast<QTcpSocket*>(sender());

                    QByteArray data = proxySocket->readAll();

            qDebug()<<"READ TRANSFER SIZE..."<<data.size();

                    QString host = proxySocket->peerAddress().toString();
                    QByteArray    filtered(data);

                    QTcpSocket *socket  = qobject_cast<QTcpSocket*>(proxySocket->parent());
                    int wSize           = 0;
                    if (!data.trimmed().isEmpty())
                    {
                        wSize = socket->write(filtered);
                        if (wSize==-1)
                             qDebug()<<"WP error";
                        else
                             qDebug()<<"TRANSFER WRITE SIZE = "<<wSize<<" READ SIZE"<<filtered.size();

                    }

                }

            void WebProxy::closeConnection() {

                    QTcpSocket *proxySocket = qobject_cast<QTcpSocket*>(sender());
                    if (proxySocket) {
                        QTcpSocket *socket = qobject_cast<QTcpSocket*>(proxySocket->parent());
                        if (socket)
                            socket->disconnectFromHost();
                        if (proxySocket->error() != QTcpSocket::RemoteHostClosedError)
                            qWarning() << "Error for:" << proxySocket->property("url").toUrl()
                                    << proxySocket->errorString();
                        proxySocket->deleteLater();;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use `QTcpServer` in a multi-threaded way.

Subclass `QTcpServer`, overload `QTcpServer::incomingConnection(int)`, create your `QThread` derived handler (described next) and start it with `QThread::start`

Subclass `QThread`, make the constructor accept an `int` (the socket descriptor), overload `QThread::run()`. In the run function, create `QTcpSocket`, call `QAbstractSocket::setSocketDescriptor` to initialise the socket, connect up the socket slots and call `QThread::exec()` to start the thread event loop.

Make sure you create the socket in the `run` of `QThread`, not the constructor so the socket is associated with that thread.

For more details, look at the [Threaded Fortune Server Example](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/network-threadedfortuneserver.html)